# Trigger Email After 5 Business Days

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

when case is closed, after 5 business days an email should be triggered. and during these 5 days the case closed should remain checked? anyone help me to achieve this!!

Answer (score 0):

add time trigger 5 days after when case closed  instead of add workflow action